# Is there a way to run a hook script when accepting a GitHub Copilot suggestion?

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

My company recently created an AI usage policy that states that developers are allowed to use AI tools to generate code for use in our codebase. It stipulates, though, that all AI-generated code must be called out with a comment. The intent behind the policy is to highlight possibly ill-informed chunks of code that might be more error-prone than others (entire functions or classes generated by AI, code with security implications, *etc.*). Ultimately, the buck stops with the developer and reviewer, but this could be a good flag to have.

Of course, there's no way to enforce this on an organizational level, nor is there a way to enforce the habit on an individual level, when using an AI code generator is as easy and unconscious as tab-completion (like with the Copilot VS Code extension). I'd like to automate this somehow to make compliance as painless as possible.

I'm imagining including a config in each repo that would fire off a hook script each time a dev accepts a suggestion. If the file doesn't already have one, it'll add a comment to the top of the file to the effect of “This file was created in whole or in part by generative AI.”

Does Copilot have an API for this? Could this be done with prompt customization? Is there another, low-friction way devs could have these comments generated for them? Most of us use VS Code.

Comment: sounds tricky. ideally gotta not mess up shebangs, or other language-specific top-of-file things.

Comment: Ah, good call-out. We don't have many files that work this way (mostly Rails & React), but that would be a tricky thing to debug.